# How to group data after cellFilter is applied UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, grouping, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

**Does grouping always happen on the actual field data or can it be down after cellFilter is applied ?**
like we can do it in filter and sorting using `sortCellFiltered: true, filterCellFiltered: true`

http://plnkr.co/edit/eswSZSnEgu620ft9npwy?p=preview

look at the `I` column the raw value is a number between `0,4` and a `cellfilter` is applied which change the value to `true` if value is `0,1,2` and `false` other wise. *see how grouping is messed up*

Answer (score 3):

FYI the grouping is still Beta at this time. Also you may take alook at this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3930).
I also have a couple of note

- priority start at 0, see [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.api:ColumnDef).
- type is required on sort, see [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef).
  It's doesn't not cost you much to specify that, to avoid unexpected behaviour.

#### Possible approach :

use the angular filter directly after XHR call resolve like so

```
data[i].i= $filter('reverse')(data[i].i);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9tMwY4?p=preview

It may not answer your question but i hope it help.

Comment: yes, using filter on the data itself will fix the problem, but otherwise this seems like a bug right ?